# Copying Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, copy

Is there a good way to duplicate Strings in Java? I know I could do some concatenation hacks, but I want to know if there is a more elegant solution.

I want copy each string in an ArrayList a certain number of times.  However, the array list seems to not allow the same object multiple times.  I'm looking for a way to duplicate the string so that I can add it to the ArrayList.

```
public class MyClass {
  ArrayList<String> myArrayList;

  /*more code*/

  public ArrayList<String> duplicate(int timesToCopy) {

      ArrayList<String> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
      for(String s: myArrayList) { //cycles through all strings
        for(int i = 1; i <= timesToCopy; i++) { //adds them timesToCopy amount of times
          newArrayList.add(s); //doesn't work, only adds it once
        }
      }
      return newArrayList;
  }
}
```

If I enter an ArrayList with value {"cat", "dog"} as I call duplicate(3), I should get {"cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "dog"}

But instead, I get {"cat", "dog"}.

I tried replacing

```
newArrayList.add(s);
```

with

```
newArrayList.add(new String(s));
```

but it still doesn't work.

Maybe I have a bug in another part of my code?

EDIT:

Ok, I don't know what happened, but it somehow worked after I didn't do anything.

EDIT 2:

Ok, the problem reappeared.  However, I figured out the problem!  I was calling duplicate(3) like it was a void function, thinking it would change the instance's ArrayList instead of returning a new one.  I am so dumb.

Comment: Did you remember to assign the result from `duplicate` or were you just re-iterating over `myArrayList` cause it works just fine for me. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/y0VH4w (maybe you're looking at the original `ArrayList` by mistake?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain how you're calling your method, but I would pass in the input `List` like so

```
public static List<String> duplicate(List<String> al, int n) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : al) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ret.add(s);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(duplicate(Arrays.asList("dog", "cat"), 3));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[dog, dog, dog, cat, cat, cat]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.util.Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29), which, well, makes *N copies* of the object passed to it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> duplicate(List<String> myArrayList, int timesToCopy) {
    ArrayList<String> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s: myArrayList) { //cycles through all strings
        newArrayList.addAll( Collections.nCopies(timesToCopy, s));
    }
    return newArrayList;
}
```